# After downloading XCode, it doesn't show up on my disk

Tags: xcode, download, app-store, installation

Today, on my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.10.3, I launched the App Store application and downloaded XCode 7. After the download has ended, I cannot find any update file on my disk. App Store says XCode 7 is installed, but indeed it's not. The XCode application on my disk is still the old version 6.4 and there is no trace of the XCode 7, nor an installer on my disk. I launched XCode 6.4 hopefully some upgrading should have been launched afterwards, but nothing happened. The About window confirms: it's the version 6.4 (6E35b). I turned off the machine and rebooted. Nothing changed. So I downloaded XCode 7 once again. Same trouble. Any idea? Solution?

Comment: In the meantime I upgraded to OS X 10.10.5. Same trouble. Also, on App Store, il looks that I downloaded XCode 7.0 twice (2nd and 3rd line) and the button to download is still enabled with the title "Update" (1st line), so I could download XCode 7 once again. That's a bug. Any workaround please?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find another way to install XCode 7 try to install the XCode 7.1 beta. Works fine for me: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Answer (score 0):

At the Apple Developer Forum I have seen that other developers had the same trouble. Anyway, after downloading XCode 7 for the 3rd time, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: A few days later, I have been able to re-download XCode 7 from App Store, and it got properly installed. Don't know how. Anyway, great.